# Must I loop to search results for a specific value?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a table in the database:

```
name         Opinion
Tim          Tim has an opinion
John         other random text
Dan          Dan's random text
Al           Al says something else
```

I call this data and get it back in

```
getRecords.lastResult
```

To access John's opinion, I could use:

```
getRecords.lastResult[1].opinion
```

But that's only because I know that `John` is the second record (record 1), but this may change. So the right way is to search through the results to first find the record index for `John`, then access his `opinion`.

My guess is I need some sort of a loop? Is there an easier way to search for `John` directly without a loop?

Comment: What format is your response in (JSON, XML, E4X, etc...) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if getRecords returns n records and John has to be on one of them
you can do it in As3 and do a loop around your Arraycollection until you find John.

Or

Do some server logic to return john data given a search string ("john") if unique.